# How does the nested class with override work?

Tags: c++

I was wondering how can one explain this mechanism:

```
class Base{
  class Other;
  virtual void test() = 0;
};
class Other: Base{
  virtual void test() override;
};
void Other::test(){ /*do something*/}
```

It looks like I have a base class called Base. It contains of a nested class which inherits from the Base. So if I call:

```
Base obj;
obj.test(); <-- it trigers the test() function from the Other class, doesn't it?
```

What is the difference between the given example and the following:

```
class Base{
  virtual void test() = 0;
};
class Other: Base{
  virtual void test() override;
};
void Other::test(){ /*do something*/}
```

what would be the benefit of hidding the Other class in the Base class?

Comment: Code samples 1) and 3) are equivalent except for a redundant declaration in the first one. 2) Doesn't even compile.

Comment: You cannot instantiate an object of class `Base` because it has an abstract method `test()`. You need to first derive a class from `Base`, define method `test()`, then instantiate an object of your derived class. In other words, you are saying that objects of class `Base` will have a method `void test()` that derived implementations will provide.

Comment: The benefit of hiding `Other` inside `Base` would be mainly encapsulation. Not that different from nested namespaces (I will be crucified for this).

Comment: For first watch it may look unrelated, but [this movie explains](https://youtu.be/zHiWqnTWsn4) true power of this mechanism.

Comment: One more thing: You are mentioning "nested class" in the title and you have forward declaration of it in code. This declaration does nothing in your code, it introduces symbol `Base::Other` which is not defined and not used, you define a class `Other` in global scope and this class is (should be) used by your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration of `class Base::Other` at line 2 in your first code example, has nothing to do with the declaration of `class Other` in line 5 of your first code example.

That is, the forward declaration of `Base::Other` does not match class `Other`.

There is benefit in having nested classes (for example, some implementations of the pimpl idiom do that), but to define the nested class, you would have to define it with:

```
class Base::Other {...}; // explicit specification of Base here
```

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> class Base{
>   virtual void test() = 0;
> };
> Base obj;  // #0
> ```

`#0` is ill-formed as `Base` is an [*abstract class*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class), as it has at least one *pure abstract member function*.

> #### Abstract class
>
> Defines an abstract type **which cannot be instantiated**, but can be
> used as a base class.
>
> A pure virtual function is a virtual function whose declarator has the
> following syntax:
>
> ```
> declarator virt-specifier(optional) = 0
> ```
>
> [...] An abstract class is a class that either defines or inherits
> **at least one function for which the final overrider is pure virtual**.

Dynamic dispatch on polymorphic objects happens when you are dispatching to a virtual function from a base pointer or reference, which (for the specific runtime call) references a derived object.

In the following example:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void test() const = 0;
};

struct A final : public Base {
    void test() const override {}; // #1   
};

struct B final : public Base {
    void test() const override {}; // #2   
};

void f(Base const& b) { 
    b.test();  // #3
}
```

the call to the virtual member function `test()` at `#3` can dispatch to either `A::test()` or `B::test()`, depending on the argument to the function `f`.

```
f(A{});  // 'test()' call in 'f' dispatches to #1
f(B{});  // 'test()' call in 'f' dispatches to #2
```

---

> what would be the benefit of hidding the Other class in the Base class?

In your original example, the `Base` class declares a *nested class* (but does not define it) to itself, meaning the `Other` class declared in `Base` is not the same as the `Other` class that derives from it.

- Declaring nested classes within a class is a separate topic entirely orthogonal to class inheritance hierarchies
- A *forward declaration* outside of a base class that intends to forward declare a derived class that the base class thinks *may* derive from it would be an anti-pattern, as the whole point with abstract (interface) classes is to provide a public client API that can be used polymorphically by different derived classes. In other words, a base class should generally never (need to) know about its derived classes (save for the special case of static polymorphism via the curiously recurring template pattern).